# Issue with mongorestore

Tags: mongodb

I am using [this](https://npmjs.com/package/mongodb-backup) mongo backup package to run a backup against my mongodb instance and it created three folders for my 3 collections in my db.

So backup looks like following:

--dbbackup/collection1/bson_files

--dbbackup/collection2/bson_files

--dbbackup/collection3/bson_files

Now I am trying to restore above backup with following command:

```
mongorestore --db dbrestore --collection collection1 
--drop /dbbackup/collection1/
```

but it's failing with following error:

```
Failed: error scanning filesystem: file /dbbackup/collection1/ is a directory,
not a bson file
```

How do I successfully restore my backup?

Comment: Don't you mean [`mongodump`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) was used to create the backup ? Show the options you used to do the backups. The `--db` and `--collection` options are deprecated in favor of `--nsInclude` or other `--ns*` options. Also kind of off-topic and really should be on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hey sorry, typo. I am actually using https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-backup to trigger the backup programmatically. My code is very similar to https://github.com/hex7c0/mongodb-backup/blob/1.6/examples/web_stream.js